# Hive on Spark CDH5.7 Execution Error

Tags: apache-spark, hive, cloudera-cdh

I've updated my cluster to CDH 5.7 recently and I am trying to run a Hive query processing on Spark.

I have configured the Hive client to use the Spark execution engine and Hive Dependency on a Spark Service from Cloudera Manager.

Via HUE, i'm simply running a simple select query but seem to get this error at all times: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 3 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask

Following are the logs for the same:

```
ERROR operation.Operation: Error running hive query: 
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 3 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.toSQLException(Operation.java:374)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runQuery(SQLOperation.java:180)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.access$100(SQLOperation.java:72)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$2$1.run(SQLOperation.java:232)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1693)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$2.run(SQLOperation.java:245)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any help to solve this would be great!

Comment: this only says that the execution of the query failed... you should look at the Spark UI to understand what happened...which is your query?

Comment: I tried a complex join query which gave the this issue, so I changed the query to select count(*) from db_name, only to get the same error.

Comment: you should look at the Spark UI to know which is the problem..

Comment: This is what I'm getting: Caused by: org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Encountered unregistered class ID: 16
Serialization trace:
colExprMap (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FilterOperator)
childOperators (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator)
aliasToWork (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.MapWork)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is due to a open JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-11519. You should use another serialization tool..

Comment: Doesnt really solve my problem, but its okay, I'll just wait for the fix. Thank  you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Execution Error, return code 3 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask
```

is not the real error message, you'd better turn on the DEBUG info by using hive cli, like

```
bin/hive --hiveconf hive.root.logger=DEBUG,console
```

and you will get more detailed logs, such as, those are something i got before:

```
16/03/17 13:55:43 [fxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx4 main]: INFO exec.SerializationUtilities: Serializing MapWork using kryo
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.deser.BigDecimalDeserializer$.handledType()Ljava/lang/Class;
```

this is caused by some dependency conflicts, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-13301 for detail.